# problem while handling text area with javascript

Tags: javascript

the script is not working:
please find the reason n remedy?

```
function validate() {
        if(document.complain.complain.value == '' || document.complain.complain_subject.value == ''){
            alert("Hey! you can't left a field blank!");
            return false;
        }
 else if(document.complain.complain.length >100) {

            alert("Sorry!post the complain within 100 characters");
            return false;
            }

        else{
            return true;
        }

    }
```

the form is:

```
<form name="complain" method="POST" action="complains.jsp" onsubmit="return validate();">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="complain_subject"
            value="Complain Subject here" maxlength="30"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><textarea rows="6" name="complain" cols="73"
            value="Complain body here" maxlength="100"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="complain" name="operation"><input
            type="reset" value="Reset" name="B2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: when i m calling validate() its getting called if the text area is empty n showing the alert.but if i post a message greater than 100 characters then the alert is not showing

Comment: s/complain/complaint/g --  complain is a verb.

Comment: I would like to complain about this question, but I'm going to need more than 100 characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for

```
document.complain.complain.value.length
```

or

```
document.getElementById ( "complain" ).value.length
```

Also I don't think there is a [maxlength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534157%28VS.85%29.aspx) attribute to textareas.

Comment: ya maxlength attribute to text area doesnt work.i just wrote it to remember the allocation size of this field in the database

Comment: thanx a lot.this really helped.thax a lot again

Answer (score 4):

Try checking the length of the value rather than the length of the element.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
else if(document.complain.complain.length >100) {
```

is wrong.

It should read:

```
else if(document.complain.complain.value.length >100) {
```

Also, as a general principle, I would advise to use local variables to make the code more readable. In addition, I would recommend to do the same thing in the same way, so if you have to compare for maximum length, then use the length property also to check for the minimum length. Finally, a function like this can get very hard to follow because you have multiple exit points. I'd suggest to do something like:

```
function validate() {
    var form = document.complain, 
        complaintMinLength = 1, complaintMaxLength = 100
        complaintSubjectMinLength = 1,
        complaintLength = form.complain.value.length,
        complaintSubjectLength = form.complain_subject.value.length,
        valid, msg
    ;
    if (complaintLength < complaintMinLength || 
        complaintSubjectLength < complaintSubjectMinLength) {
        valid = false;
        msg = "Hey! you can't leave a field blank!";
    } else if (complaintLength > complaintMaxLength) {
        valid = false;
        msg = "Sorry! Your message exceeds the maxumum length of " + complaintMaxLength + " characters.";
    } else {
        valid = true;
    }
    if (!valid){
        alert(msg);
    }
    return valid;
}
```